# Compare two pandas columns and return index of first that matches element of second

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

Say we have 2 separate dataframes, with an integer index.

```
df1
                    dta  
0  2016-11-09 01:02:00
1  2016-11-09 01:04:00
2  2016-11-09 01:06:00

df2
                    dtb    
0  2016-11-09 01:04:00
1  2016-11-09 01:04:00
2  2016-11-09 01:04:00
3  2016-11-09 01:06:00
```

I am trying to get a relatively quick way of returning a list of index values from `df1`, where all
`dtb` from `df2` are equal to `dta` in `df1`. Of course we don't have to use dates here, I just
happen to be working with them at the moment.

So in the above case our result list would be `[1,1,1,2]`.

Thanks.

Comment: are values of `df1.dta` unique?

Comment: @Andy L Yes, but `df2` are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df1.dta` is unique, so it is simple using `get_indexer`

```
ix = df1.set_index('dta').index
ix.get_indexer(df2.dtb)

Out[1219]: array([1, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas'`Index` and `get_loc`:

```
df2.apply(lambda row: pd.Index(df1.dta).get_loc(row.dtb), axis=1)
```